# Which tense should be used after word after

Tags: tense

what is the correct tense after the word **after**?

- to do something after a child **will** be born
- to do something after a child **is** born

Comment: Have you researched this at all? :)

Comment: The first is unlikely. The second is common, along with **was born** and **has been born**

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to say.  Please edit your question to add more detail, explaining the exact context?

Comment: Before, or unless, this question is closed, provide at least a couple of the example sentences that might be on your mind.

Answer (score 1):

> **I want to call the baby Mihira after she is born**.
>
> **I want to call the baby Mihira after she will be born**

I think the first sentence sounds natural to me because the second sentence is grammatically incorrect.

There is a rule in English that says that only simple present must be used **after**  for future references.

Here is a link

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/after

Comment: Answers should explain “why”.  See the [“Submitting Answers that merely answer the question” discussion on meta.](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117). Thank you for trying, but Please [Edit] and improve this answer by **providing your reasons** or usage examples from good sources.

Comment: @whiskeychief.Thank you.I have edited and improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use *after **will*** to talk about one future event that happens after another future event. Use it with the word *when*.

> *Our second child will be born **after when** our first child **will** be born.* (Neither child has been born yet.)
>
> *The teacher will tell us the test date **after when** (she tells us) the paper **will** be due.* (The teacher has not told us either the test date or the paper's due date yet.)

If you are unsure, the best choice is *after **is***. It sounds more natural and covers more situations.

> *Our second child will be born **after** our first child **is** born.* (Neither child has been born yet.)
>
> *The teacher will tell us the test date **after** the paper **is** due.* (The teacher has not told us the test date, but we know the paper's due date.)